# Why is my virtual Ubuntu IP address "10.0.0.x", but everything in my networks is "192.168.1.x"?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu in VirtualBox and its IP is `10.0.0.x`. But everything in my network is `192.168.1.x`. Why is that?

And it looks like Ubuntu is configured for dynamic IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the IP it gets by default from the DHCP server built into virtualbox.